# Why ubuntu 22.04 USB cable keyboard lights do not light up

Tags: keyboard, backlight

I have a laptop and I use an extra USB cable keyboard for it but its lights don't work in ubuntu system, my laptop's keyboard doesn't have a light function so I use an extra keyboard but it doesn't work lights either

I am in the terminal
`xset -led 3 xset led 3`
I tried the command, it worked once at first, but after turning on my laptop, these commands didn't help either

Answer (score 0):

In order to turn on external keyboard baklight on ubuntu 22.04, follow the steps:-

STEP 1

Method to switch from Wayland to X ** this step is compulsory **

Edit the configuration file,

`sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

to uncomment [remove # from] the line containing

`WaylandEnable=false`

save the file (ctrl + x and after that y ('yes') or another key for non-English and finally Enter) and reboot.

STEP 2

Method One

1. open a terminal
2. `sudo xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock`
3. enter your password
4. press the scroll lock key to see if your back light comes on

Method Two

1. open a terminal
2. `xset led on`